# "Remote" attribute doesn't work (ASP.net MVC)

Tags: asp.net, validation, data-annotations

I'm trying to validate my NewPassword property using [Remote], but it doesn't show any message error on web page, when other property's validation works. What's wrong?

**Controller action**

```
    public JsonResult VerifyNewPassword(ChangePasswordViewModel m)
    {
        return Json(false);

        //return Json(true);
    }
```

**Model**

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "New Password is required.")]
    [Remote("VerifyNewPassword", "AccountController", ErrorMessage="Error")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you tried you're endpoint via browser ?
Does it work?

Comment: Hi serhiy, did the answer resolves your problem?. If it did, please mark the answer to help future user. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could be in the `Remote` data annotation, because you have specified the *controller* using the full name, but you need only the first part.

Try this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "New Password is required.")]
[Remote("VerifyNewPassword", "Account", ErrorMessage="Error")]
...
```

and pay attention to the parameter of the method, should be like:

```
public IActionResult VerifyNewPassword(string newPassword)
{
    if (!_userService.VerifyPassword(newPassword))
    {
        return Json($"Password does not respect security standard.");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: I've already try doing this, but it doesn't help me too.

Comment: I set a break point on this action method, but program doesn't even use it.

Comment: Could you please share your controller code?